# How to refer to the Label in flowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, label, flowlayoutpanel

How can I modify dynamically added elements in FlowLayoutPanel?
I create the label and add it to the panel.

```
Random randNumbers = new Random();
        int amountOfNumbers = randNumbers.Next(5, 10);

        var table = flowLayoutPanel1; Label element;

        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfNumbers; i++)
        {
            int valueOfNumbers = randNumbers.Next(-101, 100);
            element = new Label();
            element.Font = new Font("Tobota", 13, FontStyle.Regular);
            element.Text = valueOfNumbers.ToString();
            table.Controls.Add(element);
        }
```

I want to click on any label in FlowLayoutPanel and change the font to bold, but how can I do that? How to refer to a specific element

Comment: You have to attach event to new element. And then get element itself from sender inside event method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Click` event to the dynamically created labels, and create a new instance of each dynamic label inside the `for loop`.
 Please read comments inside the code:

```
private void Example()
{
    Random randNumbers = new Random();
    int amountOfNumbers = randNumbers.Next(5, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfNumbers; i++)
    {
        int valueOfNumbers = randNumbers.Next(-101, 100);
        Label element = new Label();
        element.Font = new Font("Tobota", 13, FontStyle.Regular);
        element.Text = valueOfNumbers.ToString();
        // Set an name, you may want to use it
        element.Name = "lbl_" + i.ToString();
        // Add a click event
        element.Click += OnLabelClicked;
        table.Controls.Add(element);
    }

}

private void OnLabelClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Cast the object to the clicked label
    Label clickedLabel = (Label)sender;
    // Here you can also check the name of the label if you need
    MessageBox.Show(clickedLabel.Name);
    // Make the font of the clicked label bold
    clickedLabel.Font = new Font(clickedLabel.Font.FontFamily, clickedLabel.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```